# Iptables log forward

Tags: iptables

Hi i'm testing logging iptables, so for practice i start adding some rules. My problem is with this simple rule iptables `-A FORWARD -p ICMP -j LOG`  With this rule i was trying to log every ping inside my network, but it's only logging when the host is unreachable. When the ping is successful, doesn't log anything.
The ping is always from the same host with the same set of ip rules.

I have a lan at my home with a router i made with a linux server, and a switch. What i'm trying to do is to understand iptables better. So i start making test to see what happend. The one i comment here is a ping from my pc to another pc both connect to the switch and this one to the router (linux). I use ping because it easyer to see in the logs, but i undestarnd, belive, that the same is apply for the rest of the protocols. So i ping from host A to host B, and no logs appeard in iptables that it's in the router.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the packets are going *through* the device you're discussing, they won't hit the `FORWARD` rule.

Furthermore, in a typical switched network you won't see most packets anyway unless they are either directed at your host or are broadcast packets.

If you want to log every `ping` sent to or from your host, you need to use this pair of rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT --protocol icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG
iptables -I OUTPUT --protocol icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG
```

If you want the replies too, you'll need a second pair of rules for ICMP type 0. As before, I've provided two rules: one for replies returning to this host and one for replies from this host elsewhere:

```
iptables -I INPUT --protocol icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG
iptables -I OUTPUT --protocol icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG
```

Comment: thanks, although your method doesn't log my ping it does record ping from other host. I was suspecting what you said about switched network. So how can i controlled from linux router the traffic inside my network? i already block icmp forward and still works.

Comment: @Martin is your device a router? You didn't say that anywhere. Does the ping you're trying to record go through your host? You don't say that anywhere, either. Can you update your question to provide this information please